# Flat File Schema lines longer then expected

Tags: schema, biztalk, flat-file

Hello there Stackoverflow, I've been tasked with making a flat file schema as well as a map, however, our specifications are that there are 3 fields,

```
----------
Name       Length
----------
TIdentity     2
OIdentity     17
Result        2
```

However, the file that we receive is 500(ish) characters long, is there a way to make it ignore the remaning empty characters??

Thanks for any help you guys might be able to supply

Comment: Then either the spec is wrong or the source has a bug.  You should try to get those corrected first.  Question: Is each line otherwise CR|LF delimited?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely ensure the spec and sample files are correct (particularly that the spec contains any whitespace requirements/options), but assuming they are and you're just supposed to ignore the whitespace, you can create node to stuff the whitespace into and just ignore it.

Without knowing a bit more about your requirements, it's hard to say exactly how this should work.  If the whitespace is always a fixed length, make a node that expects that many characters.  If it's not always a fixed length, you may have to make a repeating node that's one character long but not the record terminator (presumably CR/LF or something of the like).  If the whitespace itself is the delimiter, you might be able to do something with the `ignore_trailing_delimiter` on the record.

Worst case scenario (whitespace is variable, you can't control the partner who sends it to you, and you can't get the FFDASM to sensibly deal with it), write a custom `Decode` component to preprocess the file and remove the extraneous whitespace.